# submitHandler not firing (jQuery validate)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, jquery-validate

In my ASP.NET MVC application, I have a form that is using jQuery validate. The validation seems to work fine (i.e. if any mandatory fields are missing, it doesn't do anything), but when a valid form exists, the page simply "refreshes" with all the data as URL query parameters and the `submitHandler` is never called (tested both as a breakpoint in the called API method and console.log inside the `submitHandler`). It has been tested in Chrome and IE.

My form is in a jQuery UI modal dialog, but that doesn't seem to matter as it doesn't work when it isn't in one either. I've been unable to find any solution, despite several similar problems here on SO. Here is my code:

Form HTML (razor):

```
<div id="modify-sale">
    <div>
        <form id="new-entry">
            <div style="overflow-y: auto; height: 475px;">
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label for="client">Client</label>
                    <div class="tt-container">
                        <input type="text" name="client" id="client" class="form-control" placeholder="Client" required />
                    </div>
                </div>  
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label for="notes">Notes</label>
                    <input type="text" name="notes" id="notes" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Notes" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label for="repId">Rep</label>
                    @Html.DropDownList("repId", new SelectList(Model.Reps, "id", "name"), "Rep", new { @class = "form-control", required = "" })
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label for="dateOfSale">Date of Sale</label>
                    <input type="text" name="dateOfSale" id="dateOfSale" required class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-inline">
                    <label for="amount">Amount</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="amount" id="amount" required />
                    @Html.DropDownList("currencyId", new SelectList(Model.Currencies, "id", "abbreviation"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;"/>
            <input type="text" name="clientId" id="clientId" value="0" hidden />
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var validator = $("#new-entry").validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            console.log("Submitted");
            var sale;

            sale.clientId = $("#clientId").val();
            sale.notes = $("#notes").val();
            sale.repId = $("#repId").val();
            sale.dateOfSale = $("#dateOfSale").val();
            sale.amount = $("#amount").val();
            sale.currencyId = $("#currencyId").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/sales/new",
                method: "POST",
                data: sale
            });

            return false;
        }
    });

    var dialog = $("#modify-sale").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 450,
        modal: true
    });

    $("#add-new").button().on("click", function () {
        dialog.dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't you add `type="submit"` to your 'Save' button?

Comment: I have another very similar form where I don't and it works fine, but I have tested that on this particular form and it doesn't help.

Comment: You should consider using `$(form).serialize()` to post data in ajax.

Comment: You should look at your error console; the clue is in there:  `undefined is not an object`.  Otherwise the `submitHandler` is working fine for me:  https://jsfiddle.net/6pp1xa0a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `submitHandler` **is** firing, but since you're triggering a JavaScript error here, everything stops at this point.

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating `sale.clientId = $("#clientId").val()`)

Use `.serialize()` to collect the form data instead of trying to capture each field separately.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/sales/new",
    method: "POST",
    data: $(form).serialize();
});
```

**DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/9rxxz821/](https://jsfiddle.net/9rxxz821/)**

---

Your original variable declaration was the root of the JavaScript error.

Should be: `var sale = {};`

DEMO:  [jsfiddle.net/v5rptdmL/](https://jsfiddle.net/v5rptdmL/)

Comment: This combined with changing my jQuery validate script bundle from `~/Scripts/jquery.validate*` to `~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js` seems to have done the trick, but I don't understand why when I have another form that worked fine and was built the exact same way. I'm also not clear on why the line `sale.clientId = $("#clientId").val()` was throwing an error when I have a hidden field with the id = clientId.

In any case, thanks for your help!

Comment: @matthew_b, the root cause is improperly declaring the `sale` object.  Should be:  `var sale= {};`